# How to replace row values in a particular column using index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frames,

data frame- 1 (named as df1)

```
index   A   B   C
1       q   a   w
2       e   d   q
3       r   f   r
4       t   g   t
5       y   j   o
6       i   k   p
7       j   w   k
8       i   o   u
9       a   p   v
10      o   l   a
```

data frame- 2 (named as df2)

```
index   C
3       a
7       b
9       c
10      d
```

I tried to replace the rows for specific indexes in the column "C" using the data frame - 2 for the data frame - 1 but I got the following result after using the below code:

```
df1['C'] = df2
```

Output:

```
index   A   B   C
1       q   a   NaN
2       e   d   NaN
3       r   f   a
4       t   g   NaN
5       y   j   NaN
6       i   k   NaN
7       j   w   b
8       i   o   NaN
9       a   p   c
10      o   l   d
```

But I want something like this,

Expected output:

```
index   A   B   C
1       q   a   w
2       e   d   q
3       r   f   a
4       t   g   t
5       y   j   o
6       i   k   p
7       j   w   b
8       i   o   u
9       a   p   c
10      o   l   d
```

So clearly I don't need NaN values in column "C" instead I want the values to remain as it is. (I mean it should change only for that particular index value).

Please let me know the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is `index` the index or just a normal column?

Comment: It is not a column, I used it to indicate index values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `index` is the actual index column, we can do `loc`:

```
df1.loc[df2.index, 'C'] = df2['C']
```

Or even more simple with:

```
df1.update(df2)
```

Output:

```
       A  B  C
index         
1      q  a  w
2      e  d  q
3      r  f  a
4      t  g  t
5      y  j  o
6      i  k  p
7      j  w  b
8      i  o  u
9      a  p  c
10     o  l  d
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for idx, row in df2.iterrows():
    df1.at[idx, 'C'] = row['C']
```